# Some generic and working Xcode project settings which lead to successful Mac App store submission?

Tags: xcode, macos, store

I built a simple app that I'd like to submit to the Apple store, but I am not sure whether my project Release settings are set correctly. I adjust a few things, based on what I could find online, but I might've created more problems than I solved.
I would very much appreciate if somebody could provide a copy of working Release settings which would sure work for my project. I don't store/read any files, the application just runs a few commands. Basically, I just need it to run and install in that /Applications folder so the user could trigger a launch.

Comment: Have you read over the developer guidelines for Mac Store submission?

Comment: yes, are you suggesting i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically use default settings, move your source code to a new project, read up the guidelines and see if anything is told to change, otherwise it's just fine. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Maybe you could also take a look at this one, perhaps you'd know the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4813241/567569

Comment: I'd like to clarify for future readers. What's a bit unclear from Apple guidelines is why you app might not get installed in the /Applications folder even if you haven't changed the path. However, they do explain that to make installation of updates easier, any consecutive version gets installed in the same location as the app before it. This means that if you ran a Built command and your app's been created somewhere in a /build directory, you have to remove that before you can test out the installation package.