# xcode Organizer "Validate" fails with the "No other information is available about the problem." message

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, submission

I have built an OSX application, it builds and runs using Xcode no problem, I have signed the code and done all the pre-submission things required by Apple. However, when I try to Validate my application in Organizer (or Submit), I get this nasty error: "The operation could not be completed. No other information is available about the problem."

The Bundle Identifier was registered on Apple's website and it matches the one I provide in the applications .plist file. I can't even think of a way to find a problem.

I ran the installer check on the bundle, and this is what I got. Perhaps the problem is with the bundle? However, according to the apple instructions, I can't add Installer Signing Certificate until I am in the submission process.

```
installer: Warning: PMBundle.pkg is not signed for store submission
installer: Installation Check: Passed
installer: Volume Check: Passed
installer: Bundle com.xxx.yyy will be relocated to /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/4612642F-468C-49B8-9331-A148DF9E20E6.apparchive/yyy.app
installer: Starting install
installer: Install 0.0% complete
installer: Install 9.1% complete
installer: Install 100.0% complete
installer: Finished install
```

(I shortened bundle id to 'com.xxx.yyy' and app name to 'yyy' in the example)

Any ideas would greatly help.

Comment: I am most certain I identified the error, but now I am waiting to hear from Apple. Will keep updating this as I hear something from them. Most likely my BundleIdentifier in iTunes doesn't match the one I created in Apple Dev account ... seems like iTunes has a trailing space in it :(

Comment: I am having the same issue did you hear anything from apple? Please post the issue/fix.thx

Comment: See Sami's answer below. That was the problem and the corresponding solution. However, now I can't submit to the Apple Store because iTunes Connect isn't recognizing my application. I am still waiting to hear from Apple on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error because i didn't have both the code signing certificates; 3rd Party Mac Developer Application and 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer.

Open keychain, click certificates in the left panel and check you have both certificates, if you don't download them both form the Mac Dev Center, if you do then check that in your release configuration in Xcode that the code sign field is set to 3rd Party Mac Developer Application.

You then need to open organiser, find your app and when you share it to test it code sign it with the 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer certificate. Make sure you manually click the drop down menu and choose the certificate because there's a bug which doesn't register your code signing value and then doesn't sign your code.

Should solve your problem.

All the best, Sami.

Comment: Sami, I was wondering maybe you'd also know a solution for this problem. After the above worked and I ended up compiling and validating correctly, I tried to Validate using Xcode Organizer and got an error that "no eligible applications were found". Apple has been trying to figure out why for a months now, but maybe you could take a few guesses?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a different cause, which I'll tack on for posterity: you have to have the iOS development tools installed in order to submit to the Mac App Store, even if you aren't doing any iOS development.

I was trying to save a little disk space in my 10.6 support partition by leaving them out. Didn't work.